# 404 error when deploying react app in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, vercel

I deploy a react, typescript project using Vite. Veployed app working fine but while refreshing a page getting a 404 error.

```
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `vercel.json` file. Then `push` or `deploy` to vercel again.

```json
{
  "routes": [
    { "handle": "filesystem" },
    { "src": "/.*", "dest": "/index.html" }
  ]
}
```